# When i execute an if condition with the continue keyword in a while loop my browser dosen't open

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <head>LOOPS</head>
    <h1 id="string"></h1>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        let w = 10;
        while(w<=15){
            console.log(w)
            if(w==13){
                continue;
            }
            w++
        };
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So...As you can see here, Whenever i live reload this on my browser(firefox, chrome) It just keeps on reloading and dosen't open but when i use the for loop and then use the if condition to skip a loop, It opens.
Please is there something i'm doing wrong, Because i just started learning javascript.

Comment: You successfully created an infinite loop :) that's why the browser hangs. When `w` reaches 13, with the `continue` you skip the `w++` statement and rerun the loop, and `w` is still 13, ...

Comment: So how do i skip a value using the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're creating an infinite loop. When you have the `if` statement and the `continue` keyword, it will skip to the next loop without incrementing `w` variable.

Comment: So how do i skip a value using the while loop?

Comment: use `break`. `continue` takes you back to the loop conditional. Continue means continue with the loop, rather than continue the rest of the code.